What are some of the bottled water brands in India you can trust?
When travelling in India keeping hydrated is very important. I don't know if you can fully trust the tap water. Is there a few bottled water brands that have a good name and are generally trustworthy for foreigners touring India?
I know there are some problems with counterfeit bottled water, is there then a grocery chain where you can shop for bottled water with confidence that the product is real?
I'm not asking for an exhaustive list just a few brands the locals can recommend.

Bisleri, Kinley, Aquafina and Himalaya are the 4 brands which come to mind though there are more.
Avoid fakes by sticking to large stores/supermarket chains (differs based on where you're visiting) or app based delivery like Instamart/Zepto even if they are a bit more expensive.
Mose fakes are poorly done, with the brand name misspelled and hence easy to avoid.

I'd also carefully inspect the genuine brand name bottles, as there is always the possibility that they've simply been refilled with whatever water was at hand.

Aquafina (by Pepsico), Kinley (by coke), Himalaya, Tata Copper.
I am not including Bisleri as there are lots of fakes and you need to cross check the spelling in minute detail. All brands do have counterfeits but not as much as Bisleri.
Having said that I am yet to find a 5 liter bottle other than Bisleri and till now I have not experienced fakes in this one


Majority of the best bottled water provider companies are listed in this answer : Bottled Water Co. in India.
I just want to add a good quality or authenticity check process, which is that after purchasing the bottle, take closer look below the cap. There will be a plastic sealed ring with the exact color of the cap. You would have to apply a bit more pressure in opening the cap if the seal is well intact. I am sharing a picture of the sealed bottle cap as well.

Most of you might already know this, but there will be possibilities that you might roam around the streets and there won't be any trusted vendor to buy the bottles from. And you eventually have to buy it from the local road side vendor.
